# How to add proxy configuration in mongo-java driver operation?

Tags: java, mongodb, proxy, mongo-java

I am trying to set **proxy setting while connecting to mongodb instance**.
I have tried with following snippet

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "abc.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");   
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "abc.com");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```

but the request is not seems pass through the proxy.
Is there any way to add **proxy configuration** in mongo-java driver api methods?

Comment: I feel mongo may not use http or https protocol to connect. So no use providing the proxy details for http/https.

Comment: I am accessing the mongo instance through the cosmosDB by directly using the mongodb-java-driver.and my server is configured with proxy also.So how to pass the request through proxy layer since we are passing the connection string through mongo-java-driver jar and rest of everything is done by at driver end..?